# Why does an aeroplane appear to be moving slowly?

Tags: everyday-life

Why does it seem that an aeroplane, even while travelling at 500 kmph at a height of $1.5\text{ km}$ (above sea level), is moving slowly?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159849/58382

Answer (score 4):

When you see things, you don't actually see distances, just angles - with a plane $1.5\text{km}$ directly above travelling at $500\text{km/h}$, this corresponds to an angular speed of:
$$
\omega = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{140\text{m s}^{-1}}{1500\text{m}}\right) \approx 0.1 \text{rad s}^{-1} \approx 5\text{deg s}^{-1} 
$$
This is approximately the same angular velocity your thumb would reach, at arm's length, travelling at $10\text{cm s}^{-1}$.